# How to make paginate retain form data while going to next page

Tags: django

I am using Django for creating a list of about 20 checkboxes on each page, for about N pages, using django-pagination. The checkbox data isn't stored as I traverse from a page to another. Is there any way to hook onto any of the page events, so that I could cache the data stored interim?

Any pointers to such APIs or similar help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [form-wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html)

Comment: Very useful, thank you! Just what I was looking for.